# How to keep page's CSS from effecting an iframe that loads an  html document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that when loaded changes a bit.  Is there some sort of reset or something i need to apply?  How do i keep the iframe's content looking the same regardless of which page it loads in?

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your styles with `:not(iframe)`

So your `CSS definition`s will look like the following:

```
:not(iframe) body div { margin:0 auto; } /* only applies styles to div's */
                                         /* inside body and not inside an */
                                         /* iframe */
```

Comment: I don't control the body's css.

Comment: what do you mean it "looks different." That mean the size of the `iframe` is constraining the proportions of the `iframes` layout and is skewing the elements?

Comment: For example the color of the anchors is changing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load the iFrame in a vacuum; once it's brought into a context where stylesheets are applied, it'll follow right along with everything else on the page. Fortunately, however, it's just a matter of building your stylesheets accordingly.

One approach would be to dedicate an ID to only that iFrame's container, such as #myiframe, and then be thorough and specific with all the styles you'd like applied. Design your stylesheets to avoid conflicts with this element, and use the `!important` declaration if you get into a pinch and need the sub-property to override inherited styles. It boils down to careful design more than anything else, and a healthy appreciation for how cascading style sheets work.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a subdomain and you put that in the iframe it will stop the css.

```
//from my.com
<iframe src="subdomain.my.com"></iframe>
```